# Merge code to draw table and move file using Rest API and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint-online, rest

Code below works to draw a table using CEWP SPO. I need to add a button on every row in the same table that would move corresponding files from it's current location to another document library in the same SPO site. File names are retrieved using FileLeafRef.

The data is pulled using the Ajax GET type and move command would use POST type. Kindly assist to merge both functions to get the desired.

Current code

```
$(function(){
        var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List_Name')/items?$top=10&$orderby=Created%20desc&$select=Reg,NBR,Date";
           $.ajax({
              url: requestUri,
              type: "GET",
              headers: {
                  "accept":"application/json; odata=verbose"
              },
              success: onSuccess,
});
  function onSuccess(data) {
     var objItems = data.d.results;
     var tableContent = '<table id="Table"><tr><th>Reg</th><th>Num</th><th>Date</th></tr>';
     for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
         tableContent += '<tr>';
         tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Reg + '</td>';
         tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].NBR + '</td>';
         tableContent += '<td>' + moment(objItems[i].Date).format("DD-MM-YYYY") + '</td>';       
         tableContent += '</tr>';
 }
   $('#Grid').append(tableContent);
   }
});
```

Move file code

```
function MoveFile(){
        var oUrl =  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Lib1/doc.docx')/moveto(newurl='/Lib2/doc.docx',flags=1)";
        $.ajax({
            url: oUrl,
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest":  $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the merged code below:

```
<script>


    $(function () {
        var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$top=10&$orderby=Created desc&$select=*,FileLeafRef";
        $.ajax({
            url: requestUri,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: onSuccess,
        });
        function onSuccess(data) {
            var objItems = data.d.results;
            console.log(objItems)
            var tableContent = '<table id="Table" style="width:100%"><tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Date</th></tr>';

            for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
                if (objItems[i].FileSystemObjectType != 1) {
                    var fileName=encodeURI(objItems[i].FileLeafRef);
                    var button = "<input type='button' value='MoveFile' onclick= MoveFile('"+encodeURI(objItems[i].FileLeafRef) +"')>"
                    tableContent += '<tr>';
                    tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].ID + '</td>';
                    tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].FileLeafRef + '</td>';
                    tableContent += '<td>' + moment(objItems[i].Created).format("DD-MM-YYYY") + '</td>';
                    tableContent += '<td>' + button + '</td>';
                    tableContent += '</tr>';

                }
            }
            $('#Grid').append(tableContent);
        }
    });

    function MoveFile(FileLeafRef) {
        var sourceFile = "/sites/NewProvision/Shared Documents/" + FileLeafRef;
        var targetFile = '/sites/NewProvision/doc1/' + FileLeafRef;
        var oUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='" + sourceFile + "')/moveto(newurl='" + targetFile + "',flags=1)";
        $.ajax({
            url: oUrl,
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div id="Grid">
```

In MoveFile function, pass a "FileLeafRef" as a parameter for the specific file name and define sourceFile/targetFile parameter for set file url dynamically.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jerry, appreciate the help. I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token and i see that the file name being passed is broken. For example, <input type="button" value="MoveFile" onclick="MoveFile('A1CDE" ab1234="" 01Jan20="" xyz.pdf')=""> where the file name should be A1CDE AB1234 01JAN20 XYZ.pdf

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is due to the blank spaces in the file name? but wonder where the ="" comes from in the file name value.

Comment: Also beacuse of the space, remove all the space in file name, will work.

Comment: Ive amended the code to fix the file name problem but now Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. As i have close to 5k files, it wouldnt be possible to remove all blank spaces in the file names.

Comment: Debug with F12, check out if some ) missing in your code snippet and if you have large files, try renaming with PowerShell https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/10/sharepoint-online-rename-files-in-document-library-using-powershell.html Currently, test some files without space for the function firstly.

Comment: Without space works perfectly. Anyway to treat files with blank spaces in file names?

Comment: tried to encode the name with encodeURI() and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Great, I just tested out, will update into the answer and if have special character, better to use GetFileByServerRelativePath https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/supporting-and-in-file-and-folder-with-the-resourcepath-api